# Count the number of recipients of the mail/message composed

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to implement a feature in my application which is, if the user shares the app link via email or text message with more than 5 people, he/she can unlock the full version of the app. I have seen this kind of method used by the apps.
(It seems possible with facebook and twitter sharing using facebook tagging and twitter mentions)

So, my question is, is there a way to implement this logic without using a webservice or any other server side method?

Is there a way to know the number of recipients that a particular email or text message sent using default email/message composer?

Comment: Hey @sajaz, how was the answer below wasn't it what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

In one of my apps I send multiple emails to all recipients in a meeting / NSArray of emails
When the email completes it's send, it's delegate method reports if the email was sent successfully, was cancelled, saved to draft etc
I then have a block that runs on sending to mark the person as being sent and email

the following code sends individual emails with an attachment to a number of users in an array

```
-(void)createEmailTo:(NSArray *)people path:(NSString *)path fileName:(NSString *)fileName subject:(NSString *)subject messageBody:(NSString *)messageBody{
//Create Email, see ccode later
FTAEmailMachine *emailComposer = [[FTAEmailMachine alloc] initMailTo:people
                                                             subject:subject
                                                         messageBody:messageBody
                                                          pathToFile:path
                                                            fileName:fileName];
//attach a dimiss block for SENT mail machines delagates, this scrolls through people in array sending them each a mail
emailComposer.dismissBlockSent = ^{
    NSOrderedSet *contactsActions =[self.contactEmailArray[self.arrayCounter] valueForKey:@"contactsActions"];
    if (self.arrayCounter <= self.emailArrayCount) {
        for (FTAAction *action in contactsActions) {
            [action setActionNoticeSent:YES]; // <-------- this is the important bit your after, i am setting a varible on the message being SENT
        }
    }
    //adjust the array count of people
    self.emailArrayCount -= 1;
    self.arrayCounter += 1;
    //Send the next mail in the array
    if (self.emailArrayCount > 0) {
        NSArray *contactEmailArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[self.contactEmailArray[self.arrayCounter] valueForKey:@"contactEmail"], nil];

                [self createEmailTo:contactEmailArray
                               path:path
                           fileName:fileName
                            subject:[self.contactEmailArray[self.arrayCounter] valueForKey:@"subject"]
                        messageBody:[self.contactEmailArray[self.arrayCounter] valueForKey:@"messageBody"]];
    }else{
        [FTAAppIdioms deleteFileFrom:path];
    }
};
//this is the blovcks that initiates if the mail was cancelled and not sent ** notice there isnt [action setActionNoticeSent:YES]; as before
emailComposer.dismissBlockCancelled = ^{

    //When the email is dismissed after being actually sent
    self.emailArrayCount -= 1;
    self.arrayCounter += 1;

    if (self.emailArrayCount > 0) {
        NSArray *contactEmailArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[self.contactEmailArray[self.arrayCounter] valueForKey:@"contactEmail"], nil];
        [self createEmailTo:contactEmailArray
                       path:path
                   fileName:fileName
                    subject:[self.contactEmailArray[self.arrayCounter] valueForKey:@"subject"]
                messageBody:[self.contactEmailArray[self.arrayCounter] valueForKey:@"messageBody"]];
    }else{

        [FTAAppIdioms deleteFileFrom:path];
    }
};

//present email as view
[self presentViewController:emailComposer
                   animated:NO
                 completion:^{}];

}
```

my email machine .h file looks like this, notice the blocks

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface FTAEmailMachine : UIViewController
<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

//designated init
-(instancetype)initMailTo:(NSArray *)people subject:(NSString *)subject messageBody:(NSString *)mesageBody pathToFile:(NSString *)path fileName:(NSString *)fileName;

//dismiss block
@property(nonatomic, copy) void (^dismissBlockSent)(void);
@property(nonatomic, copy) void (^dismissBlockCancelled)(void);
@end
```

the main method in the email machine .m file that does the work looks like this:

```
-(void)sendMailTo:(NSArray *)people subject:(NSString *)subject messageBody:(NSString *)mesageBody pathToFile:(NSString *)path fileName:(NSString *)fileName{

//check if device can send mail
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailComposer setSubject:subject];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:mesageBody isHTML:YES];
    if (people) {
        [mailComposer setToRecipients:people];
    }

    //check if there is an attachment
    if (fileName) {
        // Determine the file name and extension
        NSArray *filepart = [fileName componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *extension = [filepart objectAtIndex:1];

        // Determine the MIME type
        NSString *mimeType;
        if ([extension isEqualToString:@"pdf"]) {
            mimeType = @"application/pdf";
        } else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"csv"]) {
            mimeType = @"text/csv";
        } else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"plist"]) {
            mimeType = @"image/plist";
        } else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
            mimeType = @"image/jpeg";
        } else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
            mimeType = @"image/png";
        } else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"doc"]) {
            mimeType = @"application/msword";
        } else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"ppt"]) {
            mimeType = @"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
        } else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"html"]) {
            mimeType = @"text/html";
        }

        //attach the file to the email
        [mailComposer addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]
                               mimeType:mimeType
                               fileName:fileName];
    }

    [self presentViewController:mailComposer
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];

} else {
    //crferate a slert if device cant send mail
    [FTAAppIdioms createOkAlertWithTitle:@"Email"
                                 message:@"Sorry your device can't send emails"
                          viewController:self
                                     tag:0];
}
}
```

then the important bit for you is the delegate method, notice the dismiss blocks:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{

switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        //notice this dimissblock action
        [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                            completion:self.dismissBlockCancelled];
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:

        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        //notice this dimissblock action
        [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                            completion:self.dismissBlockSent];

        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:

        break;
    default:
    {
        [FTAAppIdioms createOkAlertWithTitle:@"Email"
                                     message:@"Sending Failed - Unknown Error"
                              viewController:self
                                         tag:0];
    }
        break;
}
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                    completion:nil];
}
```

Hopefully, you can see that adding the dismiss block allows you to set a variable (or whatever) on successful email being sent which should answer your question
personally I would probably store the result in an NSDefault Int or something similar.